# Declarative hash queries in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to declaratively specify which value to return from a Ruby hash. Ideally, I would be able to write a query that can run against a given hash, and store that query as an object (string, hash, etc).

```
# for example
hash = {
  key1: {
    key2: [
      { a: 1, b: 2 }
    ]
  }
}
query = { path: ["key1", "key2"], key: :a, where: { b: 2 } }

Library.query(query, hash) #=> 1
```

I haven't been able to find any good libraries for this. Is there a good way to query a Ruby hash like this?

Comment: You're asking us to recommend a solution, which is off-topic. "[ask]" and the linked pages will help. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

While the syntax isn't quite as nice, this (I think) does what you want without any explicit looping or conditionals:

```
>> require 'deep_enumerable'

>> hash.deep_get(:key1 => :key2)
       .find{|h| h[:b] == 2}
       .fetch(:a)

=> 1
```

If you wanted to store the query in a variable you could do it like this:

```
query =
  [[:deep_get, {:key1 => :key2}],
   [:find,     ->(h){h[:b] == 2}],
   [:fetch,    :a]]

query.inject(hash) do |h, (cmd, arg)|
  arg.is_a?(Proc) ? h.send(cmd, &arg) : h.send(cmd, arg)
end
```

This is hacky at best, and definitely not production quality in the general case, but it is a solution.

Comment: That's pretty good, but it's not as declarative as I'm looking for. It will meet my needs when I can store the details about the query in an object. I've updated my question to make that more specific.

Comment: I hear you. That would be great.